# Списки в Prolog

Tags: prolog

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема при изучении списков в прологе.
Вот так выводится просто список предметов:

```
domains
t_list=symbol*
predicates
nondeterm t(t_list)
nondeterm show
nondeterm print_list(t_list)

clauses
t_list (["физика","химия","история"]).
t_list (["музыка","биология"]).

print_list([ ]).
print_list([X|Y]) :- write(X), nl, print_list(Y).
show :- t(X), print_list(X),fail.
goal
show.
```

А вот дальше не знаю что и как создать факты или нет, что бы был в итоге примерно такой вывод:

```
Иванов. Предметы
физика    
химия    
история    
Петров. Предметы    
музыка    
биология
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возникает вопрос, какое отношение собаки (dogs) имеют к физике, химии, истории и т.д.?:)

По поводу фактов, будет что-то вроде

```
student("Иванов",["физика","химия","история"]).
student("Петров",["музыка","биология"]).
```

Чтобы получить список предметов, которые интересуют к примеру Иванова, нужно дать запрос `student("Иванов",X).` Как этот список вывести, думаю, разберетесь.